# Ruby on rails 4: showing error messages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have trouble displaying error message for invalid inputs using Ruby on rails. If anyone can help me with it? Currently new to the area.

I suspect the area is due to :user and @user.

This is my form generated on index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user, url: '/login', html:{id:"form"} do |f| %>
            <h2 class="login">Login</h2>
            <div class="form">
                <input type="name" placeholder="Name" name="user[name]" class="form-input" required /></div>

<% end %>
```

My ActiveRecord Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :uniqueness => true

    has_secure_password

end
```

I try to use the following error handling, by passing the following code after `<%= form_for :user, url: '/login', html:{id:"form"} do |f| %>` but it did not work with and showed:

**NoMethodError in Users#register
: undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass**

```
 <% if @user.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: You need to replace `@user` and `@article` with your object instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this.

/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.haml:

```
- if object.errors.any?
  .alert.alert-danger
    The form contains #{pluralize(object.errors.count, "error")}.
  %ul#error_explanation
    - object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      %li= msg
```

Then, wherever you want errors to be shown in your views, something like:

```
= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object
```

Note `object` in the method.  When you call, you could pass either an object instance from your controller or (in the above case), the object of a form builder.